# The while loop does not work when playing music via pyaudio

Tags: while-loop

I’m making GDI effects for myself, I need the while loop with GDI effects to work and at the same time for the music to be played, but the music does not start until the loop ends, how can I make the loop work and the music to play?

```
seconds_to_work = 3 #mode operating time (18 to the sound)
start = time()

while smoke:
    #GDI-effects
    color = (random.randint(0, 122), random.randint(0, 430), random.randint(0, 310))
    brush = win32gui.CreateSolidBrush(win32api.RGB(*color))
    win32gui.SelectObject(hdc, brush)
    win32gui.BitBlt(hdc, 1, 1, sw, sh, hdc, dx,dy, win32con.PATINVERT)
    win32gui.BitBlt(hdc, 1, 1, sw, sh, hdc, dx,dy, win32con.SRCAND)
    dx = math.ceil(math.sin(angle) * size * 10)
    dy = math.ceil(math.cos(angle) * size * 10)
    angle += speed / 5
    if angle > math.pi :
        angle = math.pi * -1
    #stopping the cycle by time
    if time() - start > seconds_to_work:
        break

CHUNK = 1024
wf = wave.open(current_directory + "\sound\smoke.wav", 'rb') #sound
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: You need to add which languages you are using here. My guess is you are using Python, but it would save time and assist the people who wants to answer you better if you clearly state that out.